# List all "Active" EMR cluster using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to list all active clusters on EMR using boto3 but my code doesn't seem to be working it just returns null.

Im trying to do this using boto3

1) list all Active EMR clusters

```
aws emr list-clusters --active
```

2) List only Cluster id's and Names of the Active one's
**cluster names**

```
aws emr list-clusters --active --query "Clusters[*].{Name:Name}" --output text
```

**Cluster id's**

```
aws emr list-clusters --active --query "Clusters[*].{ClusterId:Id}" --output text
```

But i'm blocked in the starting stage of using boto3

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("emr")
response = client.list_clusters(
    ClusterStates=[
        'STARTING',
    ],
)

print response
```

Any suggestions how can i convert those CLI commands to boto3

Thanks

Comment: How are you blocked? The boto3 equivalent of the CLI's --active is probably something like ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING'].

Comment: You might just want to obtain a complete list of clusters (with no filter) and then narrow-down the list in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The following codes can print the active emr name and id:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("emr")
response = client.list_clusters(
    ClusterStates=[
        'STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING'
    ]
)
for cluster in response['Clusters']:
    print(cluster['Name'])
    print(cluster['Id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

slightly updated on @shifu.zheng's answer:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client("emr",region_name = "us-west-1", aws_access_key_id = "sdufashdifos123121", aws_secret_access_key ="sjdfnsaldfoasd1231312")
response = client.list_clusters(ClusterStates=['STARTING', 'BOOTSTRAPPING', 'RUNNING', 'WAITING', 'TERMINATING'])
for cluster in response['Clusters']:
print(cluster['Name'])
print(cluster['Id'])
```

You need to have the required parameters in the boto3.client object.